# Microsoft.AspNetCore.All isn't supported.FrameworkReference for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App will be added implicitly by Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

Tags: nuget

I have a problem with my visual studio solution. Project is working but I got this error when I want to add migration. I could add migration before and downloaded the packages I need.

```
add-migration birim add-migration : The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

I tried:

```
dotnet add EmployeeData package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount
```

I got this error:

```
unable to create dependency graph file for project
```

So I added the package manually via "manage nuget packages for solution"
And now I have this error for my solution:

```
The Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package is not supported when targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher. A FrameworkReference for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App should be used instead. This will be added implicitly by Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.
```

And I got
`Build failed.`
when I tried to add migration.

I am almost sure this is about paths of projects and solutions.How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` and it's working.